# submit additional form data jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, form-data

I'm having trouble getting `$('.drop').attr('data-id')` in `formData`:

```
$('.drop').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: base_path + 'parallax/upload',
    autoUpload: false,
    replaceFileInput: false, // interferes w/ dropify
    formData: {
        id: $('.drop').attr('data-id'), // nothing
        stmt: '1', // works
        '{/literal}{$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()}{literal}': '{/literal}{$this->security->get_csrf_hash()}{literal}'
    },
    add: function (d, c) {
        console.log($(this).attr('data-id')); // works
        console.log($('.drop').attr('data-id')); // works
        console.log($('#fileupload').attr('data-id')); // works
        var a = [];
        var b = /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
        if (c.originalFiles[0]['name'].length && !b.test(c.originalFiles[0]['name'])) {
            a.push('Not an accepted file type.');
        }
        if (c.originalFiles[0]['size'].toString().length && c.originalFiles[0]['size'] > maxsize) {
            a.push('Filesize is too big; try increasing post_max_size and/or upload_max_filesize.');
        }
        if (a.length > 0) {
            bootbox.alert(a.join(''));
        } else {
            start_time = new Date().getTime();
            c.submit();
        }
    },
```

According to the [docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data), additional form data can be added via:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    formData: {example: 'test'}
});
```

Which works for my csrf token and other things I manually define, however I cannot seem to get the `data-id` of the input field in `formData`. No errors are occurring, but I do see my request being sent without the `id` attribute - if I manually define it - it works. I can also get the property in the add function.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are trying to add the value of `$('.drop').attr('data-id')` at the moment you initialize your `fileupload`class. At this time the attribute will most certainly be empty.

Try to set `formaData.id` prior to the actual upload using the `fileuploadsubmit` event as described in:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data#setting-formdata-on-upload-start

```
$('.drop').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData.id = $('.drop').attr('data-id');       
    //or in your case `this` will work, too:
    //data.formData.id = $(this).attr('data-id');       
});
```

Comment: I'm currently doing it that way actually but I wanted to try it like above because I thought it was cleaner. Why isn't the variable available at that time? The input has that attribute before the fileupload class is initialized so I find it strange that it can't be added to formdata / accessed that way

Comment: IMHO the event driven solution looks way cleaner as you can exactly tell *when* the attribute's value is collected.

Comment: But can you explain why it won't work in the above method?

Comment: Not with the code snippet you're providing. Did you take a look at the data that gets transferred (eg. in Chrome DevTools/Network tab)? Could you please add an `<input type="hidden" data-id="youchoose" />` and use its attribute's value in the fileupload/formData? Just for testing?